# Unable to use xbuild to build solution (Mono)

Tags: c#, mono

When trying to use `xbuild` to build my solution through Mono on Mac and Linux (haven't tested under Windows yet), I get this strange error that I've been unable to find anywhere else.

```
Errors:

/Users/macbook/git/DiscordSharp/DiscordSharp.sln (default targets) ->
(Build target) ->
/Users/macbook/git/DiscordSharp/DiscordSharp/DiscordSharp.csproj (default targets) ->
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.2.2/lib/mono/4.5/Microsoft.CSharp.targets (CoreCompile target) ->

    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.2.2/lib/mono/4.5/Microsoft.CSharp.targets: error : Tool executable '/MSBuild/14.0/Bin/mcs.exe' could not be found

     1 Warning(s)
     1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:02.0472770
MacBooks-MacBook:DiscordSharp macbook$
```

Interestingly enough, I am able to open the solution in MonoDevelop and build it that way. The projects in the solution target `Mono / .NET Framework 4.5`. I'm running Mono `4.2 SR1 (4.2.2.30)`.

What could be causing this issue and in what way could I fix it? This problem prevented me from using TravisCI with this project and I have yet to find a fix for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.csproj` file is only defining a non-Unix `CscToolPath` for a `Platform` conditional (`OS` should be used...), not sure what the requirement is for v14 for Windows(?), so as a test:

```
vi DiscordSharp/DiscordSharp.csproj
```

**Remove:**

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Platform)' != 'Unix'">
    <CscToolPath>$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin</CscToolPath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

**Rebuild project and it should work fine:**

```
nuget restore
xbuild DiscordSharp.sln
```

If v14 MSbuild is required for Windows, you can use the following:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(OS)' != 'Unix'">
    <CscToolPath>$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin</CscToolPath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

http://www.mono-project.com/archived/porting_msbuild_projects_to_xbuild/

Then the following should run fine with no errors:

```
xbuild /target:clean
xbuild /target:build
```

Comment: Worked! Thank you for this! Right now I'm compiling fine on Mac/Linux without the `CscToolPath` but if I run into problems on Windows, I'll try it again with `OS` instead of `Platform`.

Comment: Setting CscToolPath is a Bad Idea(tm) anyway; you select MSBuild elements with the ToolsVersion attribute on the Project element. And if you need a specific compiler (e.g. the Roslyn one), there's a NuGet package for that (but I'm not sure that's cross-platform).